# reset virtio driver from device side

Tags: linux, driver, device, reset, virtio

According [virtio specification v1.2](https://docs.oasis-open.org/virtio/virtio/v1.2/virtio-v1.2.html) there is a `DEVICE_NEEDS_RESET` flag in device status register is available.

If i set this flag with interrupt in `virtio_pci_common_cfg.mxix_config` (or 1-bit of `ISR`)  from device after successfull probe there are not any reset from driver is happens.

In linux kernel sources (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.2/source/include/uapi/linux/virtio_config.h#L44) this bit define but not used (exept mlx5_vnet.c - custom device).

What is right way to initiate guest driver reset from device side?

Thanx.

Comment: Did the driver receive a device configuration change notification?

Comment: Yes. Interrupt counter for `virtio0-config` in `/proc/interrupts` is increased.
The msix interrupt number for `config queue` and `common config` is same

Comment: That just means it generated the notification. It is up to the device driver `config_changed` routine what to do with it.

Comment: so,  [config_changed](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/virtio/virtio.c#L126) is processed [virtnet_config_changed](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/virtio_net.c#L3612) for network driver (in my case) and [virtnet_config_changed_work](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/virtio_net.c#L3579) is checked link up/down.

But what about device reset?

Comment: first of all, thx for you time.

looks like the reset driver from device side in linux is not support, am i right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According [2.1 Device Status Field of specification](https://docs.oasis-open.org/virtio/virtio/v1.2/virtio-v1.2.html) there is a `DEVICE_NEEDS_RESET` bit is enable for indicate to driver  that the device has experienced an error.

In `2.1.2 Device Requirements: Device Status Field`:

> The device SHOULD set DEVICE_NEEDS_RESET when it enters an error state that a reset is needed. If DRIVER_OK is set, after it sets DEVICE_NEEDS_RESET, the device MUST send a device configuration change notification to the driver.

According `4.1.4.3 Common configuration structure layout`, there are few type of notification (device to driver) is enable:

- common interrupt (`config_msix_vector`)
- queue interrupt (`queue_msix_vector`)

---

I play with `virtio-pci-net` deice.
In general case, it hase 3 queue: `tx`, `rx`, `control`.
Device driver set `tx_msix=2`, `rx_msix=1`, `control_msix=0`, `config_msix_vector=0`.

Device need reset case  (my sequence):

- increse `virtio_pci_common_cfg.config_generation`
- set bit `DEVICE_NEEDS_RESET` in status register
- set common interrupt in `config_msix_vector`

But driver only check control queue settings at all.

What i am doing wrong?

---

some info from my stand.

**Guest OS**

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux v-desktop 5.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Oct 12 18:33:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**PCI config space**

```bash
$ sudo lspci -vvvvvnnnxxxxxx -s 01:00.0
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio network device [1af4:1041] (rev 01)
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at c0507000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Region 1: Memory at c0506000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=1 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=1 offset=00000080
    Capabilities: [5c] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [64] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 25W
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 5GT/s, Width x4, ASPM not supported
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x4
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis- NROPrPrP- LTR-
             10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt+ EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Disabled,
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5-5GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer- 2Retimers- DRS-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance Preset/De-emphasis: -6dB de-emphasis, 0dB preshoot
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [a0] Vendor Specific Information: VirtIO: CommonCfg
        BAR=0 offset=00000000 size=0000007c
    Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: VirtIO: Notify
        BAR=0 offset=00000100 size=00000010 multiplier=00000001
    Capabilities: [c4] Vendor Specific Information: VirtIO: ISR
        BAR=0 offset=0000007c size=00000001
    Capabilities: [d4] Vendor Specific Information: VirtIO: DeviceCfg
        BAR=0 offset=00000080 size=00000018
    Capabilities: [e4] Vendor Specific Information: VirtIO: <unknown>
        BAR=0 offset=00000000 size=00000000
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable- ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=00
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Kernel driver in use: virtio-pci
00: f4 1a 41 10 06 04 10 00 01 00 00 02 08 00 80 00
10: 00 70 50 c0 00 60 50 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00
30: 00 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 00 00
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
50: 11 5c 03 80 01 00 00 00 81 00 00 00 01 64 03 00
60: 00 00 00 00 10 a0 02 00 02 80 e8 07 10 28 00 00
70: 42 60 40 01 00 00 42 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00
90: 06 00 00 00 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a0: 09 b0 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00
b0: 09 c4 14 02 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 10 00 00 00
c0: 01 00 00 00 09 d4 10 03 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00
d0: 01 00 00 00 09 e4 10 04 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
e0: 18 00 00 00 09 00 14 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
100: 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
200: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
210: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
220: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
230: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
240: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
250: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
260: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
270: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
280: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
290: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
2a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
2b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
2c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
2d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
2e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
2f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
300: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
310: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
320: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
330: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
340: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
350: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
360: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
370: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
380: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
390: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
3a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
3b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
3c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
3d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
3e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
3f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
400: f4 1a 41 10 06 04 10 00 01 00 00 02 08 00 80 00
410: 00 70 50 c0 00 60 50 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
420: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00
430: 00 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 00 00
440: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
450: 11 5c 03 80 01 00 00 00 81 00 00 00 01 64 03 00
460: 00 00 00 00 10 a0 02 00 02 80 e8 07 10 28 00 00
470: 42 60 40 01 00 00 42 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
480: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00
490: 06 00 00 00 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
4a0: 09 b0 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00
4b0: 09 c4 14 02 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 10 00 00 00
4c0: 01 00 00 00 09 d4 10 03 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00
4d0: 01 00 00 00 09 e4 10 04 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
4e0: 18 00 00 00 09 00 14 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
4f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
500: 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
510: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
520: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
530: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
540: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
550: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
560: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
570: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
580: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
590: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
5a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
5b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
5c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
5d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
5e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
5f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
600: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
610: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
620: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
630: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
640: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
650: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
660: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
670: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
680: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
690: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
6a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
6b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
6c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
6d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
6e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
6f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
700: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
710: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
720: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
730: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
740: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
750: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
760: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
770: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
780: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
790: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
7a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
7b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
7c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
7d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
7e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
7f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
800: f4 1a 41 10 06 04 10 00 01 00 00 02 08 00 80 00
810: 00 70 50 c0 00 60 50 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
820: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00
830: 00 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 00 00
840: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
850: 11 5c 03 80 01 00 00 00 81 00 00 00 01 64 03 00
860: 00 00 00 00 10 a0 02 00 02 80 e8 07 10 28 00 00
870: 42 60 40 01 00 00 42 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
880: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00
890: 06 00 00 00 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
8a0: 09 b0 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00
8b0: 09 c4 14 02 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 10 00 00 00
8c0: 01 00 00 00 09 d4 10 03 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00
8d0: 01 00 00 00 09 e4 10 04 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
8e0: 18 00 00 00 09 00 14 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
8f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
900: 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
910: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
920: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
930: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
940: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
950: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
960: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
970: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
980: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
990: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
9a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
9b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
9c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
9d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
9e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
9f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
aa0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ab0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ac0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ad0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ae0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
af0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ba0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
bb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
bc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
bd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
be0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
bf0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
c00: f4 1a 41 10 06 04 10 00 01 00 00 02 08 00 80 00
c10: 00 70 50 c0 00 60 50 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
c20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00
c30: 00 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 00 00
c40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
c50: 11 5c 03 80 01 00 00 00 81 00 00 00 01 64 03 00
c60: 00 00 00 00 10 a0 02 00 02 80 e8 07 10 28 00 00
c70: 42 60 40 01 00 00 42 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
c80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00
c90: 06 00 00 00 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ca0: 09 b0 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00
cb0: 09 c4 14 02 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 10 00 00 00
cc0: 01 00 00 00 09 d4 10 03 00 00 00 00 7c 00 00 00
cd0: 01 00 00 00 09 e4 10 04 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
ce0: 18 00 00 00 09 00 14 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
cf0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d00: 02 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
da0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
db0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
dc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
dd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
de0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
df0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ea0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
eb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ec0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ed0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ee0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ef0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
fa0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

**PCI BAR0**

```bash
$ sudo dd if=/dev/mem skip=3226497024 bs=1 count=1000 | hd
00000000  01 00 00 00 1f 00 00 80  01 00 00 00 17 00 00 80  |................|
00000010  00 00 03 00 4f 01 02 00  00 02 00 00 01 00 08 00  |....O...........|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000080  02 ac da 01 00 01 00 00  00 00 dc 05 e8 03 00 00  |................|
00000090  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000003e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           |........|
000003e8
```

**interrupts**

```bash
$ cat /proc/interrupts | grep "CPU\|virtio0"
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
 29:          1          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 524288-edge      virtio0-config
 30:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 524289-edge      virtio0-input.0
 31:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 524290-edge      virtio0-output.0
```

---

Thanks